# Go to specific desktop on TotalSpaces

Tags: spaces

I want to make the gesture "three fingers up" to to desktop 1, "three fingers left" go to desktop 2, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

try JITouch https://www.jitouch.com
or 
Better Touch Tool http://www.bettertouchtool.net